# Como filtrar datas separadas por dia , mes e ano no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-select, order-by

Olá, tenho uma tabela "Reunioes" no MySQL com a seguinte estrutura:

> id:Int(11), assunto:String(40), dia:String(2), mes:String(2),
>   ano:String(4), ativa:String(2)

salvo no campo dia o dia da reunião, mes o numero correspondente do mes da reunião, e em ano, o ano que ela ocorre.
por exemplo: uma reunião A que ocorre dia 20/04/2015
dia = 20
mes = 04
ano = 2015

gostaria de ordenar o resultado por proximidade da reunião, ou seja, a que esta mais perto de ocorrer primeiro. para isso usei o seguinte sql:

```
SELECT * FROM Reuniao ORDER BY ano ASC, mes ASC, dia ASC
```

funcionou, mas ele mostra também as reunião se já passaram (primeiro), mas preciso que mostre somente as que ainda vão acontecer. então tentei o seguinte:

```
SELECT * FROM Reuniao WHERE ano >= 2015 AND mes >= 3 AND dia >= 3 ORDER BY ano ASC, mes ASC, dia ASC
```

supondo q hoje fosse 03/03/2015 ela deveria mostrar todas reuniões que acontecem de hoje em diante, mas apresenta um erro, não mostra reuniões qualquer reunião que aconteça antes do dia 3 de qualquer mes, e do mes 3 de qualquer ano.

como resolver isso? e também mostrar somente os que ativa = "S"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os problemas são :

1) Comparar string com numero

2) ano >= 2015 AND mes >= 3 AND dia >= 3 , considerando que ambos sejam inteiros está incorreto pq por exemplo se tivermos os valores (2016 , 2 , 3) mesmo o ano sendo maior , como o mes é menor a condição vai falhar .

E uma solução:

Converter os campos separados pra Date

```
     SELECT * FROM Reuniao
     WHERE str_to_date(concat_ws(',',dia,mes,ano),'%d,%m,%Y') >= curdate() AND ATIVA = 'S'
     ORDER BY ano ASC, mes ASC, dia ASC
```

Complementando com a questão de levar em consideração a hora você pode fazer assim:

Pra  usar uma `string` com a hora na **str_to_date** você so precisa especificar o formato !

Por exemplo com o fomarto **hh:mm**

```
     str_to_date(concat_ws(',',hora,dia,mes,ano),'%H:%i,%d,%m,%Y')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou! mas tenho uma duvida, na função str_to_date, ali no concat_ws onde tem `','` antes de dia, seria o horário? se eu tivesse um campo hora no formato 22:00 eu poderia fazer assim:  `str_to_date(concat_ws(hora,dia,mes,ano)`? @JohnDiego

Comment: @AthilaZuma vo colocar na resposta !

Comment: Minha hora esta no formato 24h e isso aceita só 12h, consigo converter ela no meu programa mas mesmo assim precisaria saber como indicar ali no str_to_date o AM/PM. ou como usar no formato 24h. @JohnDiego

Comment: @AthilaZuma usa %H no lugar do %h , editei a resposta